# Rails: Controller not seeing time travel in capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails, time-travel

I'm attempting to use the `travel_to` method in ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers. I want to be able to use `visit_page` as if it were another day. I can call `Date.today` from within the block defined by the call to `travel_to`, and it gives me the date I'm trying to test for. However, when `Date.today` is called from within the controller of the page I'm visiting with capybara, it always gives me today's date.

Here's the test:

```
    it 'shows the date' do
      new_time = Time.local(2017, 11, 16, 10, 0, 0)
      travel_to(new_time) do
          puts Date.today
          visit root_path
          expect(page).to have_content '2017-11-16'
      end
    end
```

And the controller:

```
class RootPageController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @this_date = Date.today 
  end
end
```

And the test failure:

```
2017-11-16
    ...
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content '2017-11-16'
       expected to find text "2017-11-16" in "2017-11-27"
```

I have a suspicion that somehow capybara causes the call to `Date.today` in the controller to happen before my `travel_to` block in the test. Is there a way to make sure that doesn't happen? Or, could something else be going on?

Comment: It is not possible for the controller action to happen before you call `visit root_path` so that's not the issue.  The issue is more likely to be you using a JS capable driver and not having puma (or whatever server is running the app) correctly configured to run in process.  Are you using `puma` and if so what output does it create when you run your tests (if running rspec system tests you may need to un-silence the puma output).

Comment: Hi, I'm not using a JS capable driver, just rack_test. I made sure there was no javascript so the issue wouldn't be confused by that. Maybe I'm making assumptions about how travel_to works. This seems to be the basic use case though. Have you used it that way?